# Use a certain font from a website

Tags: html, css, web, fonts

I want to use the font 'Semplicita Pro' from the site https://worldofwarcraft.com/en-gb/ for my own website project but I can't seem to find the font file on the website. Even if I should be able to get my hands on the file, would it be legal to use the font?

Comment: I dont think so its related to programming?

Comment: i think tha't the font is not for commercial use but you can easily download the font and linked it with your web site with css.

Comment: @Nadim can you explain how to extract the font file from said website? I don't find the reference to the font file in the source code.

Comment: Sorry but i don't now if this allowed in this community or not so i can't answer to this question i just answer you about programming issue , but google it i am sure that you will reach for what you ask about , you can also search in [dafont](http://www.dafont.com/) it's quite nice site for fonts but don't forget to read the **licence** of the font before you download.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues instead of directly about programming. **[See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1402846)** for details and the **[help]** for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is premium font which could be bought there:
https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/canadatype/semplicita-pro/

This is kind of expensive. Maybe you could use one of the alternatives to this font?
https://www.typewolf.com/google-fonts

Comment: I found a font very similar to the one I wanted on the google fonts website. (at least when used in caps) It's called 'Josefin Sans', https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Josefin+Sans

Comment: Great choice :)